# Blocks to UIElement conversion

Tags: flowdocument, uielement, fixeddocument

Is it possible to convert a `System.Windows.Documents.Block` to `System.Windows.UIElement`?

I need this as I want to add the blocks I created to a fixed document.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

For if someone still needs to know this, it's pretty easy.

Just use a BlockUIElement to contain the UIElement.

For instance, if you were to attach a Border element to a table's cell:

TableCell cell = new TableCell(new Border()); //won't work!

TableCell cell = new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(new Border())); OK!

Comment: Isn't this reversed to how the OP wants it? You di UIElement -> Block, he wants Block -> UIElement